# how to select 10 random records for 3 items that all 3 items exist in the selection

Tags: oracle, random

I'm working with Oracle and got the problem I'm not sure how to solve.
I have many stores and each one of them sells 3 items.
I need to select random records for each of those 3 items from each store,
but the amount of the records must be no more than 10 for each store
and each store has to sell at least one of each item.

The select I have now selects 10 records for each store
but it selects one item (usually the last one)

```
select *
FROM
(select store_id,item_id, product_name
row_number() over(partition by store_id order by item_id) as MyCount
from table5 order by dbms_random.value)
where MyCount<=10
```

How do I make it select all 3 items and <=10 records all together for each store?

Sample data:

```
Id Store_ID Item_ID  Product_ID 
------------------------------
1  11723    13048841 2 
2  11723    13332688 2 
3  11723    08981562 4 
4  11723    08872923 4 
5  11723    01030632 5 
6  11723    01029557 5 
7  11723    01010174 5 
8  11723    01031526 5 
9  11723    01032479 5 
10 11723    01000285 5
```

Comment: I think you should put `order by dbms_random.value` in your partition by clause instead of item_id. Can you show some sample data?

Comment: Thank you! It helped a little. I have 2 items now in the result, not 1. It still doesn't select all 3.

Comment: Actually, you are absolutely right! That store sells only 2 items. The other select has all 3 values. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Unfortunately, that code doesn't necessarily selects all 3 items, sometimes it's just 2. How I can make sure that all 3 items are selected?

Comment: can you show some sample data? or create a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: Count Store ID Item ID Product ID1 11723 13048841 2

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to format the comments. :) Unfortunately, it comes as  text, not by columns.

Comment: Count Store ID Item ID Product ID
*1 11723 13048841 2
*2 11723 13332688 2
*3 11723 08981562 4
*4 11723 08872923 4
*5 11723 01030632 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May not be truly random, but this ensures all three items are present in the result. Is it good enough?

```
SELECT id,
       store_id,
       item_id,
       product_id
  FROM (SELECT id,
               store_id,
               item_id,
               product_id,
               ROW_NUMBER ()
                  OVER (PARTITION BY store_id ORDER BY r1, DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE)
                  r2
          FROM (SELECT id,
                       store_id,
                       item_id,
                       product_id,
                       ROW_NUMBER ()
                       OVER (PARTITION BY store_id, product_id
                             ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE)
                          r1
                  FROM mytab))
 WHERE r2 <= 10;
```

Demo at [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fdbeb/2).